# Is a ListItem GUID List dependent?

Tags: sharepoint-online, splistitem

Picture the scenario:

**ListA, ListB, ListC, ListR**

In **ListR**, I have a field (fGUID) to store the GUID of an Item of one of the A,B,C Lists.

Do I need to store the List[A,B,C].GUID to locate the ListItem?
I mean, can I refer the ListItem using its GUID outside the context of its containing List?

Thank u.

Answer (score 1):

GUIDs are globally unique. You should never find two things with the same GUID in any system anywhere. A programmer has made a mistake if you do.

So to answer your question - no, List Item GUIDs are not list dependent.

Comment: Rob, you are a bit incorrect. GUIDs are not globally unique, but a probability of getting a duplicate is so low that you're more likely to get hit by a meteorite. 32768 times.

Comment: I didn't realize that was the case. However, whether they are or are not actually globally unique, systems treat them as if they are. For example, if SharePoint were to have two resources (e.g. Features, Lists, Webs) with the same Id, it would cause the system to malfunction.

Comment: Thank you! Whatever they are globally unique or not , can I query a ListItem without referring it's containing List?